# Searching for a change in a cell and outputting address of changed cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro which will scan through a range of cells and detects when anything has been entered in this range (Other than N/A). It will then return the cell location to the user.

This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim v, x As Range

For Each v In Range("E4:BJ14")
    If v.Value <> "N/A" And IsEmpty(v.Value) = False Then
        Set x = v.Address
        MsgBox x
    End If
Next v
```

V outputs the text in the box when I have MsgBox v but I can't seem to output the address.

Is there something really obvious that I'm missing?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: An `.Address` is a `String`, not a `Range`.

Comment: `Dim v, x As Range` is not the same thing as `Dim v As Range, x As Range`

Comment: `v.Value <> "N/A"` is just begging for a `Type Mismatch` error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rInt As Range

    Set rInt = Intersect(Target, Range("E4:BJ14"))
    If rInt Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If rInt.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Text = "N/A" Then Exit Sub

    MsgBox Target.Address
End Sub
```

*(for single-cell changes)*
*(not for changes due to formula re-calculation)*